# uitableview not showing data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sqlite, ios-simulator

i followed the tutorial -> http://icodeblog.com/2008/09/02/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-2/

but the thing is my uitableview isnt showing anything from database!! i did an nslog and able to query the data..so what could be the possible error?

i went through line by line with the source..but still can't find any problem..anyone tried the tutorial and face similiar problem as me?

Answer (score 2):

Delegate and Datasources are connected?

Comment: found the problem..i was running on 3.1.2 where it could only run on 3.0...such a fool...

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the sample code and it works with no problems under OS 3.0 and 3.1.2 and

http://icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/todo-part-21.zip

Comment: yep..i mean i am able to run the sample code, but i am en-counting problem with my own app..which i wanted to know..i do not want to face the same problem in the future not knowing wat's solution eh!